# Hunter fan/light remote in parallel with wall switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I have a Hunter Dempsey fan/light with remote controller connected to a wall switch via 3-wire cable (black, white, and bare copper). I assume that installing it the way manual tells me to *((ceiling) black/(remote) black, (ceiling/fan/remote) white/white/white, (ceiling) copper/(fan) green-yellow, (remote) blue/(fan) blue, (remote) yellow/(fan) black)* would install them in series - that is, requiring both switches to be active to control the fan. What I want to do is a) to have remote and wall switch control the light independent of each other, and b) (optionally) hardwire the fan to be controlled by the remote irrespective of position of the wall switch. How exactly do I do it?

Here is the default wiring scheme (grey = white):
[image: Default wiring]
Would switching black and white wires at the receiver work?
[image: An option?]

Comment: Switching white/black is _NEVER_ the answer!!! (There are a _few_ exceptions, but not if your house was wired after the mid-2000s.)

Comment: A single pole switch will turn off the power completely if off.  Using the black/hot just prevents your bare skin from touching hot playing with the fan.  Using the white will mean hot is at the fan to knock you down(maybe six feet under).

Comment: das is verboten ....

Comment: There are lines of products you can use that, essentially, make the wall switch a remote control. Then you can mate another, mobile, remote control. That way, either can control the light and fan. Since product recommendations are not allowed, I will not give specific names, but your local hardware store can help you find what you need.

Comment: How many wires can you run between the switch and fan?